Custom chapter entry in TOC - description + image
I would like to create a TOC with a chapter block.
The block would be composed of :

chaptercontent
And thechapter in Roman number in light grey behind chapter content. ~x2 Height.
chapterdescription bellow
mychaptertoc decoration image bellow


I got a part of the layout but I have issue to :

Make the chapterinfo entry use a dedicated etocsetlevel
Define the chapter block to stay in the same column

\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{etoc} % tocloft not recommended with KOMA. toctitle?
\usepackage{graphicx} % For my picutre
\usepackage{lipsum} % For generating dummy text
\usepackage{multicol} % For generating dummy text
\usepackage{tikz}



\etocsettocstyle
{\begin{multicols}{3}}%Nothing before
{\end{multicols}}%Nothing after

\etocglobaldefs % necessary for \etocname etc... to survive - from texexchange post

\etocsetnexttocdepth{section}
\etocsetlevel{chapterinfo}{1}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
afterindent=false,
beforeskip=0mm,
afterskip=5mm,
pagestyle=empty,
]{chapter}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}} % Roman number
\renewcommand{\chapterformat}{} % No chapter label
\let\oldChapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}[2]{%
    \pagestyle{headings}% mystyle goes here
    \oldChapter[#1]{\& \space #1 \space \&} \par % Add left & right decoration in heading but not in toc and header
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapterinfo}{\detokenize{\numberline {I}}\noexpand#2}%
    \includegraphics[height=30mm]{example-image}\par % my decoration goes here from a variable
    \chaptermark{#1} % Can be handle by KOMA SCRIPT headingtotoc option?
}

\etocsetstyle{chapter}
    {\vspace{5mm}}%Start
{}%prefix
{
    \centering {
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
            \node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, text=lightgray, scale=3] (roman) {\textbf{\etocnumber{}}};
            \node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=center] at (roman.center) {
                \fontsize{12}{0}\selectfont \uppercase{\etocname}
            };
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \par \vspace{2mm}
        {\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image}}
    }\par
}%content
{\vspace{5mm}}%finish

\renewcommand{\thesection}{} % no numbering

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents*
    
    \chapter{Introduction}{My intro precis.}
    
    \section{Welcome}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \section{One last thing}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    
    \chapter{Methods}{The Methods explanations come here.}
    \section{Doing it that way}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \section{Or the other way}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \section{By the way}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \section{See also}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    
    \chapter{Results}{Finally, we conclude that it is fine.}
    \section{It is alive!}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \section{What is next?}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    
\end{document}

